# MS Bot Emulator - keep the microphone on?

Tags: botframework

Does anyone know of a way to force the bot emulator microphone to always stay on (keep listening?) so that I can converse with a bot (and not have to keep pressing the microphone icon in the bottom right?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this behaves in the Emulator, but you might want to try setting the `InputHint` of the message to `ExpectingInput`.

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-input-hints#expecting-input) (these are from the `Node.js` version but is also possible in `C#`).

#### Expecting input

To indicate that your bot is awaiting a response from the user, set the message's input hint to `builder.InputHint.expectingInput`. On many channels, this will cause the client's input box to be enabled and microphone to be open. The following code example creates a prompt that indicates the bot is expecting user input.

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, 'This is the text that will be displayed.', {                                    
    speak: 'This is the text that will be spoken initially.',
    retrySpeak: 'This is the text that is spoken after waiting a while for user input.',  
    inputHint: builder.InputHint.expectingInput
});
```