# speech to text in microsoft botframework using c#

Tags: c#, botframework, speech-to-text

I created a bot using microsoft botframework in c#. Now I am using speech recognition, in that I want to know one thing, can we control microphone on/off instead of clicking it for every question in webchat if it is not possible then please tell me how can we give speech as input and get output response in text from bot. Now it is giving text as response when I give text as input and speech as response when I give speech as input but I want it should respond in text when I give speech as input.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using v3 or v4 of the bot framework?

Comment: Can you helo me in how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the SDK version you are using.

For v3, there are no out-of-the-box solutions you can use. As mentioned in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138445/how-to-turn-on-always-the-microphone-in-bot-framework-direct-line?rq=1), you may need to code a custom solution yourself to meet your needs. However, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151392/ms-bot-emulator-keep-the-microphone-on) suggests that there may already be a solution you could possibly adapt to your needs.

For v4, there is no out-of-the-box solution at this time, but it is under consideration with some development already performed. Read that discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/859).

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the mic to turn on after the bot speaks to you, you need to set the `inputHint` on the activity to `ExpectingInput`. If you always want that and you don't send multiple messages at a time, then you can set it with an ActivityMapper (v3) or a Middleware (v4). Just a note that with v3 the `ExpectingInput` breaks on ios. I'm not sure about v4 though. Below is an example middleware (v4) I have that sets the `inputHint` to `ExpectingInput` if the text or attachment ends with a "?".

```
public class TextToSpeechMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        turnContext.OnSendActivities(OnSendActivities);
        turnContext.OnUpdateActivity(OnUpdateActivity);

        return next(cancellationToken);
    }

    private Task<ResourceResponse> OnUpdateActivity(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity activity, Func<Task<ResourceResponse>> next)
    {
        ConvertTextToSpeech(activity);
        return next();
    }

    private Task<ResourceResponse[]> OnSendActivities(ITurnContext turnContext, List<Activity> activities, Func<Task<ResourceResponse[]>> next)
    {
        foreach (Activity currentActivity in activities.Where(a => a.Type == ActivityTypes.Message))
        {
            ConvertTextToSpeech(currentActivity);
        }

        return next();
    }

    private void ConvertTextToSpeech(Activity message)
    {
        Activity initialMessage = message;

        try
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
                    {
                        if (message.Attachments[0].Content is HeroCard attachment)
                        {
                            message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(attachment.Text);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(message.Text);
                    }

                    message.Speak = message.Speak.Trim();

                    if (ignoreList.Where(i => message.Speak.ToLower().StartsWith(i.ToLower())).Count() != 0)
                    {
                        message.Speak = null;
                        ignoredSpeak = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Speak))
                {
                    message.Speak = null;
                }

                if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak) && (message.Speak.EndsWith("?") || message.Speak.StartsWith("Is this correct?")))
                     || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text) && message.Text.EndsWith("?")))
                {
                    message.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;
                }

                // IOs won't work with expecting input
                if (message.Recipient.Name.EndsWith(":ios"))
                {
                    message.InputHint = InputHints.AcceptingInput;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            message = initialMessage;
        }
    }
}
```